# Serialization InvalidClass best practice

Tags: java, file, serialization

I am making an application in Java which uses files to store information with serialization. The trouble I ran into was that everytime I update one of my classes thats being store I obviously get `InvalidClassException`. The process I am following for now is that I just `rm` all the files and rebuild them. Obviously thats tidious with 5 Users,and I couldnt continue it with 10. Whats the standard best practice when updating Serialized objects to not lose the information from the files?

Comment: hi & welcome! see, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/285793/592355

Answer (score -1):

Mostly?

Stop using java's baked-in serialization. It sucks. This isn't just an opinion - the OpenJDK engineers themselves routinely raise fairly serious eyebrows when the topic of java's baked in serialization mechanism (`ObjectInputStream` / `ObjectOutputStream` comes up). In particular:

- It is binary.
- It is effectively unspecified; you will never be reading or writing it with anything other than java code.
- Assuming multiple versions are involved (and it is - that's what your question is all about), it is extremely convoluted and requires advanced java knowledge to try to spin together some tests to ensure that things are backwards/forwards compatible as desired.
- The format is not particularly efficient even though it is binary.
- The API is weirdly un-java-like (with structural typing even, that's.. bizarre).

### So what should I do?

You use an explicit serializer: A library that you include which does the serialization. There are many options. You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to turn your object into a JSON string, and then store that. JSON is textual, fairly easy to read, and can be read and modified by just about any language. Because you 'control' what happens, its a lot simpler to tweak the format and define what is supposed to happen (e.g. if you add a new field in the code, you can specify what the default should be in your Jackson or GSON annotations, and that's the value that you get when you read in a file written with a version of your class that didn't have that field).

JSON is not efficient on disk at all, but its trivial to wrap your writes and reads with `GZipInputStream` / `GZipOutputStream` if that's an issue.

An alternative is [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). It is more effort but you end up with a binary data format that is fairly compact even if not compressed, and can still be read and written to from many, many languages, and which also parses way faster (this is irrelevant, computers are so fast, the bottleneck will be network or disk, but, if you're reading this stuff on battery-powered raspberry pis or what not, it matters).

### I really want to stick with java's baked-in serialization

[Read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html), then. The specific part you want here is what `serialVersionUID` is all about, but there are so many warts and caveats, you should mostly definitely not just put an svuid in and move on with life - you'll run into the next weird bug in about 5 seconds. Read it all, experiment, attempt to understand it fully.

Then give up, realize it's a mess and ridiculously complicated to test properly, and use one of the above options.